# Implementation of a Session-ID as part of HttpSession?

Tags: java, security, http, session, httpsession

I am developing a new kind of an HttpServer,
I would like to support the HttpServer Java-like functionality
how does one implement such a feature?

All I know is that you need to generate a long session-id unique string and send it via a cookie which expires after configurable number of minutes, and you need to renew this cookie upon every response.

but is it secures enough? why no one can try to guess session-ids string and try to hijack someone else session?

Answer (score 0):

If it's long enough, it will stand up to brute force attack for a while.  If you don't use SSL somebody else could be able to 'sniff' the session key over the network.

Comment: How long should it be? that's the only security measure? (lets say that people can't sniff this network)

Comment: There can be other measures. For example you can require that that session is bound to a particular IP Address. That can help a bit, though it doesn't work too well via proxies.  The other bit of popular security is to protect against XRF attacks. Basically each page generates a new additional nonce, and that has to be returned each time.

Answer (score 0):

The SecureRandom class is a good place to start if you want to start generating good-enough session IDs. There are a few other things to watch out for, most notably the size of the generated ID amongst others. You could refer to the the paper "[Secure Session Management With Cookies for Web Applications](http://www.isecpartners.com/files/web-session-management.pdf)" for additional details. The section discussing the generation of entropic values is probably what you need.